# Automating facebook messages on facebook if certain conditions are available

Tags: facebook, automation, message, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to do add a feature in my facebook page messages:
it's to remind page followers about something at a certain time and this "something" depends on what they choose or if they are online or no:
**for example:**

- If a user sends "A" to page messages it automatically sends him "a" at
  2:00 everyday.
- If he typed in "B" it automatically sends him "b" at 4:00 every day.

**so my question is:** is there a website or a tool that lets me do this, or should i code it using something like selenium

Comment: Facebook only allow you to use the API. And message bots can only respond to messages. Not spam people over time.

Comment: which api  ?....

Comment: There is no API to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use One Time Notification system. If your user agrees to get a one time notification, you can send that user message only once. After that, user have to agree to get notification again to get the next notification message.

You can read about Facebook Platform Policies here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy/policy-overview/